# Prevent login from cookie stealing in browser's developer panel

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I'm been implementing a login system for my website and i discovered that if i change the session-id in the developer panel in my browser (Press F12 > Application > Cookies > My Site) i can actualy login in another account, it is possible only and if i know the session-id from someone else, but is there any way to avoid it or is it normal and the security of the session-id should be focused in the database and on the users computer?

Sorry if this is something basic, i'm still learning how to use sessions and cookies.

this is my session script:

```
<?php

class _account {

    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $authenticated;
    private $updateTime;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->id = NULL;
        $this->username = NULL;
        $this->authenticated = FALSE;
        $this->updateTime = NULL;
    }
    
    public function __destruct(){
        
    }

    public function login(string $username, string $password): bool {
        global $conn;
        $conn->link = $conn->connect();

        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
            if($stmt = $conn->link->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE username = ?")){
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
                try{
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    throw new Exception('Erro ao conectar com a base de dados: '. $e);
                }
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                    $stmt->bind_result($db_account_id, $db_account_password);
                    $stmt->fetch();

                    if(password_verify($password, $db_account_password)){
                        session_regenerate_id();

                        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $db_account_id;
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        if(!isset($_SESSION['updateTime'])) $_SESSION['updateTime'] = strtotime('NOW');

                        $this->id = $db_account_id;
                        $this->username = $username;
                        $this->authenticated = TRUE;
                        $this->updateTime = $_SESSION['updateTime'];

                        if(!$this->isActive()){
                            $_SESSION['exceptional_error'] = ERROR_LOGIN_DENIED;
                            $this->logout();
                        }

                        //Verify if the current password's hash needs to be updated to newest algorithm
                        if(password_needs_rehash($db_account_password, $password)){
                            if($stmt = $conn->link->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ? WHERE id = ?")){
                                $stmt->bind_param('si', $new_hash, $refer_id);

                                $new_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                                $refer_id = $db_account_id;
                                $stmt->execute();
                                echo '<div class="box-msg sucess" style="top:100%;">Hash updated to a newly version!</div>';
                            }
                        }

                        /* Register the current Sessions on the database */
                        $this->registerLoginSession();

                        return TRUE;
                    } else{
                        $stmt->close();
                        $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
                        throw new Exception(ERROR_LOGIN_PASSWORD);
                    }
                } else{
                    $stmt->close();
                    $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
                    throw new Exception(ERROR_LOGIN_USERNAME);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
            throw new Exception(ERROR_LOGIN_BLANK);
        }
    }

    private function registerLoginSession(){
        global $conn;
        global $browser;
        $conn->link = $conn->connect();

        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            if($stmt = $conn->link->prepare("REPLACE INTO users_sessions (session_id, user_id, login_time, user_agent, user_OS) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?, ?)")){
                $stmt->bind_param('siss', $session, $userid, $user_agent, $user_OS);
                $session = session_id();
                $userid = $this->id;
                $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $user_OS = $browser->getPlatform() .' '. $browser->getPlatformVersion(true);

                /*
                $browser->setUserAgent($user_agent);

                echo $browser->getName();
                echo $browser->getVersion();
                echo $browser->getPlatform();
                echo $browser->getPlatformVersion(true);
                */

                try{
                    $stmt->execute();
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    throw new Exception('Erro ao conectar com a base de dados: '. $e);
                }
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    public function regenerateSession($userid): bool{
        global $conn;
        $conn->link = $conn->connect();

        if($stmt = $conn->link->prepare("UPDATE users_sessions SET users_sessions.session_id = ? WHERE users_sessions.session_id = ? AND users_sessions.user_id = ?")){
            $stmt->bind_param('ssi', $newSession, $actualSession, $userid);
            $actualSession = session_id();
            session_regenerate_id();
            $newSession = session_id();

            try{
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                throw new Exception('Erro ao conectar com a base de dados: '. $e);
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
            return TRUE;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function sessionLogin(): bool{
        global $conn;
        $conn->link = $conn->connect();

        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            if($stmt = $conn->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM users_sessions, users WHERE (users_sessions.session_id = ?) AND (users_sessions.login_time >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND (users_sessions.user_id = users.id) AND (users.active = 1)")){
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $session);
                $session = session_id();

                try{
                    $stmt->execute();
                    //$result = $stmt->get_result();
                    $result = $this->get_result($stmt);
                    //$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    $row = array_shift($result);
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    throw new Exception('Erro ao conectar com a base de dados: '. $e);
                }
                if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

                    $this->id = $row['id'];
                    $this->username = $row['username'];
                    $this->authenticated = TRUE;
                    $this->updateTime = $_SESSION['updateTime'];

                    $differenceBetweenTimes = (strtotime('NOW') - $this->updateTime);
                    $minutesToUpdate = $differenceBetweenTimes / 60;

                    if($minutesToUpdate > 30){
                        //Atualiza o id da sessão a cada X minutos
                        if(!$this->regenerateSession($this->id)){
                            $this->logout();
                        }
                        $_SESSION['updateTime'] = strtotime('NOW');
                    }                   
                    return TRUE;
                } else if($this->getFileName() == 'cpainel.php'){
                    //Não redireciona, o usuário já está na página inicial
                } else{
                    $this->logout();
                }
            }
            $this->logout();
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->disconnect($conn->link);
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function isAuthenticated(): bool {
        return $this->authenticated;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: If you know someone's session ID you can impersonate them, that's just a fact. That's why session IDs are long random strings, ideally transmitted over SSL.

Comment: Some places will also tie a user's session to more information such as user agent and/or IP. These don't guarantee security, but they do add to the complexity to impersonate. Some systems will also prompt a user to "upgrade" their security if they are provisionally authenticated, if the request is more (potentially) damaging and/or sensitive.